# Spark job fails in AWS Glue | "An error occurred while calling o86.getSink. The connection attempt failed."

Tags: python, pyspark, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I attempted to migrate data from a csv file from an S3 storage to a table in my Redshift cluster. I took reference from an autogenerated code which came after I built blocks using Visual mode in AWS Glue. This job ran successfully.

I copied that code and changed basic details such as variable and table name in the Spark script I wanted to run under the different job. FYI, I gave all necessary permissions and attached required policies for the job to run and have set the VPC and security group rules.

Here's my code given below.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue import DynamicFrame

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node S3 bucket
node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={"quoteChar": '"', "withHeader": True, "separator": ","},
    connection_type="s3",
    format="csv",
    connection_options={"paths": ["s3://testbucket-mohit/Source/AMH.csv"]},
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node1",
)

# Script generated for node Amazon Redshift
node2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=node1,
    connection_type="redshift",
    connection_options={
        "redshiftTmpDir": "s3://aws-glue-assets-765579251507-ap-south-1/temporary/",
        "useConnectionProperties": "true",
        "dbtable": "public.amh2",
        "connectionName": "redshift",
        "preactions": "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.amh2; CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.amh2 (id VARCHAR, owner_name VARCHAR, property_name VARCHAR, address_line1 VARCHAR, city VARCHAR, state VARCHAR, zipcode VARCHAR, country VARCHAR, square_feet VARCHAR, property_type VARCHAR, year_built VARCHAR, url VARCHAR, cityurl VARCHAR);",
    },
    transformation_ctx="node2",
)

job.commit()
```

The data successfully loads into dynamic frame however when it comes to writing data to redshift, it throws below error.

```
23/10/10 09:07:56 INFO LogPusher: stopping
23/10/10 09:07:56 INFO ProcessLauncher: postprocessing
23/10/10 09:07:56 ERROR ProcessLauncher: Error from Python:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/testrun.py", line 26, in <module>
    node2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awsglue/dynamicframe.py", line 640, in from_options
    return self._glue_context.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(frame,
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awsglue/context.py", line 337, in write_dynamic_frame_from_options
    return self.write_from_options(frame, connection_type,
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awsglue/context.py", line 355, in write_from_options
    sink = self.getSink(connection_type, format, transformation_ctx, **new_options)
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awsglue/context.py", line 317, in getSink
    j_sink = self._ssql_ctx.getSink(connection_type,
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o86.getSink.
: java.sql.SQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at com.amazon.redshift.util.RedshiftException.getSQLException(RedshiftException.java:56)
    at com.amazon.redshift.Driver.connect(Driver.java:319)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$.$anonfun$connectionProperties$5(JDBCUtils.scala:1061)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$.$anonfun$connectWithSSLAttempt$2(JDBCUtils.scala:1012)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$.$anonfun$connectWithSSLAttempt$1(JDBCUtils.scala:1012)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$.connectWithSSLAttempt(JDBCUtils.scala:1012)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$.connectionProperties(JDBCUtils.scala:1057)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper.connectionProperties$lzycompute(JDBCUtils.scala:820)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper.connectionProperties(JDBCUtils.scala:820)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper.getRawConnection(JDBCUtils.scala:833)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.RedshiftDataSink.<init>(RedshiftDataSink.scala:39)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getSink(GlueContext.scala:1121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at com.amazon.redshift.core.RedshiftStream.<init>(RedshiftStream.java:86)
    at com.amazon.redshift.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:111)
    at com.amazon.redshift.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:224)
    at com.amazon.redshift.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
    at com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.RedshiftConnectionImpl.<init>(RedshiftConnectionImpl.java:328)
    at com.amazon.redshift.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:474)
    at com.amazon.redshift.Driver.connect(Driver.java:295)
    ... 24 more
```

Even I tried to run below cell block in AWS Glue's Jupyter Notebook, still it gives below error.

```
node2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=node1,
    connection_type="redshift",
    connection_options={
        "redshiftTmpDir": "s3://aws-glue-assets-765579251507-ap-south-1/temporary/",
        "useConnectionProperties": "true",
        "dbtable": "public.amh2",
        "connectionName": "redshift",
        "preactions": "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.amh2; CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.amh2 (id VARCHAR, owner_name VARCHAR, property_name VARCHAR, address_line1 VARCHAR, city VARCHAR, state VARCHAR, zipcode VARCHAR, country VARCHAR, square_feet VARCHAR, property_type VARCHAR, year_built VARCHAR, url VARCHAR, cityurl VARCHAR);",
    },
    transformation_ctx="node2",
)
```

Am I missing something here? Thank you in advance.